# I want to override the gridview HeaderStyle. Currently skin(through theme) is applying

Tags: asp.net, css, themes

I want to override the gridview HeaderStyle.
Currently skin(through theme) is applying on my gridview.
I only want to override is headerstyle,want to give my own CSS.
How can I do this.

Thanks in advance

**Edit_*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvSports" runat="server"> 
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="Blue" ForeColor="Navy" />

....List of Columns

</asp:Gridview>
```

Skin File(App_Themes>Default>skinFile.skin)-----------------------------

```
asp:GridView runat="server">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Green" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="Gray" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to give blue color(backcolor) in HeaderStyle, but it takes Green due to skin file(please check skin code)

**I only want to override HeaderStyle**

Comment: It would be nice to see some code, to have a better picture of the situation

Comment: Sven check please.I updated the question with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a new skin with a skinid for this purpose.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSports" runat="server" SkinID="BlueGrid"> 

....List of Columns

</asp:Gridview>
```

and for the skins you keep your old one for the gridvievs generally and an additional one for your special case.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Green" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="Gray" />
</asp:GridView>

<asp:GridView SkinID="BlueGrid" runat="server">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Blue" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="Gray" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: First of al thanks for your reply.I don't want to any change in skin file.Is it possible to code only in gridview file,if yes then how

Comment: The problem is that you want to change the header style per inline css (BackColor will be rendered out as style="background-color:..."). The skin file does exactly the same. So what you are doing in the moment is overwriting your attributes in the control with your skin, because the skin gets rendered after the control attributes.

Comment: Yes I know but I am searching for property like 'EnableTheming' that is associated with control or some technique

Comment: the other way would be to give the skin you have a skinid and then give every gridview you want the skin attached to also that skinid. Another way I don't see in the moment.